# Getting data from PHP controller into Vue

Tags: php, symfony, vue.js, twig

I have a backend written in PHP, frontend with Twig templates and Vue components. I'm trying to pass data from my PHP controller into my Vue component, and I'm really not sure how to do this.

Let's say I have this in my controller:

```
    return $this->render('setting/setting.html.twig', [
  'title' => 'Your Etsy Settings',
  'tab' => 'Settings',
  'sub_title' => 'integrated with etsy',
  'message' => '',
  'settingForm' => $form->createView(),
  'storeId' => $store->getId()
]);
```

How can I access 'title' in my Vue component? Part of my template is Twig, and then I'm rendering my Vue components inside the Twig template.

Comment: You'd have to pass them to the Vue component (as a prop) within the Twig template. Something along the lines of `<your-vue-component :title="{{ title }}">`. (Sorry, I don't know Twig's syntax exactly, but that's the basic idea.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is {{}} then you can swap

```
new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}']
})
```

...

```
<your-vue-component :title="${ {{ title }} }">
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters